# What is "tracking" on a bench power supply?

Tags: power-supply, test-equipment

I'm looking at buying a bench power supply. Some of them have Constant Voltage / Constant Current (CV/CC) listed as a feature, and that I understand. But some also list **tracking** as a feature. What does tracking mean in this context? Why would I want that feature?

Comment: Speaking of features, a supply that beeps when it current limits can save a lot of debugging time.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A tracking feature on a dual (or more) output supply means that one output can track another. This allows you to set up, for example, positive and negative supplies for opamp circuits that are always symmetrical and can be adjusted from a single knob or parameter.